# How to change size in imageCapture.takePhoto()?

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, navigator

I need to change the size of a photo from imageCapture.takePhoto() but it is not working.I need to change the size to 320 height X 240 width but the result is 640 height X 480 width.

Here you can found the documentation.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/takePhoto

```
navigator.getUserMedia(
{
 video:true,
 audio:true
},
function(localMediaStream) {
 const track = localMediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
 let imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
 imageCapture.takePhoto(
   {imageHeight:320,imageWidth:240}).then(function(blob) {
    //do somethingh with blob (photo)
 }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
 });
},
function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Ps: navigator.getUserMedia is deprecated. Use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia instead.

Comment: Thanks that is really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to check the *PhotoCapabilities* of your ImageCapture before being able to use the *photoSettings* parameter of *ImageCapture.takePhoto(photoSettings)*.

To do so, you will call the [`getPhotoCapabilities()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/getPhotoCapabilities) method of your *ImageCapture*, and then check the ranges set as `imageHeight` and `imageWidth`.

```
const capture = new ImageCapture(track);
const { imageWidth, imageHeight } = await capture.getPhotoCapabilities();
const width = setInRange(required_width, imageWidth);
const height = setInRange(required_height, imageHeight);
const photoSettings = (width && height) ? {
  imageWidth: width,
  imageHeight: height
} : null;
const pic = await capture.takePhoto(photoSettings);

function setInRange(value, range) {
  if(!range) return NaN;
  let x = Math.min(range.max, Math.max(range.min, value));
  x = Math.round(x / range.step) * range.step; // take `step` into account
  return x;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bLrvyet5/

But it may very well happen that your required width and height are not in these *MediaSettingsRange*, and thus you may have to resize this image yourself on a canvas.