# How to change the default capture image size in imageCapture.takePhoto()?

Tags: angular, getusermedia, image-capture, mediastream, mediacapture

I have this code below and I want when I take the photo to resize the photo size. I have tried the getPhotoCapabilities and getSettings but it is not working. Can someone help me please?? I am in angular component

```
try {
      this.imageCapture.takePhoto()
      this.imageCapture.takePhoto().then(blob => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          const base64 = reader.result;
          const capture = new Capture(base64.toString());
          capture.id = this.imagesCaptured;
          this.currentCaptures.push(capture);
          this.imagesCaptured++;
          this.captureImage();
        };
     });
```

Comment: What do you mean "resize the photo to portrait?" Please [edit] your question to be specific.  For example: *when I get a 1280x720 image from takePhoto, I want to clip off the left and right sides of the photo to get an image size of 576x720*.

Comment: Yes that is correct basically, resize the photo from 1280x720 to anything like 570x720 or customized the size using the imageCapture.takePhoto() parameters. How do I achieve that??

Comment: Have you tried setting the video.width and video.height constraints when you call `getUserMedia()` to the desired dimensions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change size in imageCapture.takePhoto()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226802/how-to-change-size-in-imagecapture-takephoto)

Comment: I have tried to provide width and height on constraint which the video picks the dimention but after taking the photo, the photo is displayed in original sizes - @O. Jones, I have tried that too but does not work for me